# testing true/false for while conditions using ! || and && operators

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm having a little trouble grasping the difference between ! || and && when they are tested in a while condition. In the example below I want the program to ask a question "do you see a four on the screen?" then if the person answers no the program continues and keeps asking. If the user enters the answer "yes" the program exits but mine does not. 
In my while loop condition am I telling the while loop to continue only if both i is less than 5 and the answer to the question is not yes? How is the correct way of thinking about ! || and && when used inside the context of a while loop?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class WhileConditionTestProgram extends ConsoleProgram{
public void run(){

String question = ("do you see a four on the screen? ");
int i = 1; 

   while(i <= 20 && !(question.equals("yes"))){
     String question = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
     i++;
     }

   }
  }
```

Comment: Watch carefully, the variable names inside the while loop, and the one you have used in the condition.

Comment: You don't ever update `answer`, so it never equals `"yes"`.

Comment: `String question = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (formerly "too localized").


Comment: @rohitjain Sorry that was a typo. I just fixed it. I changed the question a couple of time before i posted it.

Comment: @JessicaM.. Now you are re-declaring the variable inside the while loop. That creates a different block-scoped variable, which is different from what you have in while loop condition.

Comment: @JigarJoshi You don't need to declare the type of `question` twice.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking exactly.  You do appear to me to be correct in your understanding, but why not just try it and see if it works as you expect?

Comment: Sorry it does work I just had a typo in my Eclipse. It does work now.

Comment: @2rs I just pointed out error line

Comment: @JigarJoshi Ahh I figured you were suggesting OP do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These operators work in a while loop the same way as they work everywhere else.

The && and || operators perform Conditional-AND and Conditional-OR operations on two boolean expressions.

Try this:

```
String answer = "";
int i = 1; 

   while(i <= 20 && !(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))){
     answer = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
     i++;
     }
```

Comment: You need to remove the redeclaration "String answer" inside the while loop.  You are shadowing the answer variable with a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the obvious issue of variable re-declaration, you should also consider using a `do-while` loop, since you are reading the user input at least once.

So, you can better change your loop to:

```
int i = 0;
String answer = "";

do {
    answer = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
    i++;
} while (i <= 20 && !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

Note: I have used `equalsIgnoreCase` just for safer side, since you are reading input from user. You never know what combination of letters it passes.

Answer (score 3):

In your while condition you are testing answer not question try that:

```
while(i <= 20 && !(answer.equals("yes"))){
 answer = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
 i++;
 }
```

Comment: Just make sure you declare `answer` first (referring to OP's current code)

Comment: fwiw it might be better practice to use `answer.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead - but this is just for interest

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code:

```
String question = ("do you see a four on the screen? ");
int i = 1; 

while(i <= 20 && !(question.equals("yes"))){
    String question = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
    i++;
}
```

Is that you're redefining the `question` variable inside the while function.  As an example, this will print "1", and not "2":

```
String question = "1";
int i = 1;

while (i <= 20) {
    String question = "2";
    i++;
}

System.out.println("Question is: " + question); // This will print "1"!
```

When you say `String question = "2"` you are declaring a brand new variable called `question` and setting it to "2".  When you get to the end of the while loop, that variable goes out of scope and the program throws its data away.  The original `question` is untouched.  Here is a corrected version of that code snippet:

```
String question = ("do you see a four on the screen?");
int i = 1; 

while(i <= 20 && !(question.equals("yes"))){
    question = readLine("do you see a 4 on the screen?: ");
    i++;
}
```